# Complex Ring Isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a problem with something in abstract algebra. The problem is the following:

Prove or disprove that the mapping $\theta: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $\theta(a+bi)=a-bi$ is a ring isomorphism.

I know that it should be an isomorphism. I know how to show that the mapping is one-to-one, and I know how to show that the mapping respects both addition and multiplication as defined in $\mathbb{C}$. But how would you clearly show that $\theta$ is onto?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can't you find an explicit inverse mapping ?

Comment: That would work because a mapping is only invertible if it is one-to-one and onto, right? That would be the justification behind it?

Comment: Yes, indeed, it is equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll prove the map is onto: Take $z\in \mathbb C$, let $z=a+bi$. Then $\theta(a-bi)=a+bi=z$. So the map is onto.

Comment: Okay, I'm still a little confused. How exactly does that show that the mapping is onto?

Comment: @A.S.Hopkins This answer just showed how **any** $\;a+bi\in \Bbb C\;$ has an inverse image, namely $\;a-bi\;$ , under the map $\;\theta\;$ . This is *exactly* what being surjective means.

Comment: @A.S.Hopkins what is your definition for a map being onto ?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling Our definition of an onto map is one which has the entire codomain as the image of the domain.

Comment: right, so you have to pick an element of the codomain, and show it is in the image right?

Comment: Yes, so this mapping would show that the whole of the codomain is the image of the map?

Comment: well yeah, you want to show every element in the codomain is in the image. So take $z$ in the codomain, now let $z=a+bi$, then $z$ is in the image. Why? because $z=\theta(a-bi)$.

Comment: That makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Conjugation is its own inverse. Hence its is both one-to-one and onto.